# Fail to install wazuh API

Tags: node.js

I already installed the wazuh manager on RHEL 7. Now I'm trying to install the wazuh API. I installed nodejs 4.6.1 as the wazuh installation guide suggests, ran the configure file, make and make install commands and node. v works, but when I try to install wazuh-api-3.3.1-1.x86_64.rpm using rpm, an error pops up saying nodesj >= 4.6 is needed. Anybody knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered in the Wazuh repository at GitHub: https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh/issues/837